# Suppressing Details, Header, and Footer when Condition is False

Tags: crystal-reports

This seems really easy to do, but its simply not working for me and I have searched others questions and I don't know if they ever corrected them or not, but here is my situation.

I have this setup below.

1 Group Header
2 Group Header
Details
2 Group Footer
2 Group Footer

I want to suppress Details, Group Footer 2, and Group Header 2 based off the running total formula (displayed in GF 2) which determines if everything added through the details = 0. I have an additional formula in GF 2 that basically says if the running total formula  doesn't equal 0 and will display true or false. Example here...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKoNm.png)
As you can see because the total comes to 0 it will display false because the formula is setup to see if it doesn't equal to 0.

I then add a suppression formula to the details section, GH2, and GF2 section that checks to see if the formula displays False and then it should suppress those sections, however, only the GF2 is actually being suppressed. Actually now that I look at it, one part of the details section is actually being suppressed which I am not sure why. Here is the image. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXadJ.png)

Is it because I am using a running total instead of a manual running total? I tried to switch to that and I was receiving the same result. Again, I am using the same exact formula in each suppression condition for each GH2, Details, and GF2.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual I was able to answer the question after a couple more hours of frustration... but here is what I did.

I stopped basing the suppression off of if the formula in the GF2 was False and put an actual formula in the suppression formula for all three groups.

That formula was (The column being the quantity I was adding to see if it   was 0)

```
 SUM({Table1.Column1},{Table1.Group2})=0;
```

Once I put that formula in all of the suppression conditions... it worked.